# How many margins could be there?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

This wiki [page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marginal_distribution) says

> In probability theory and statistics, the marginal distribution of a subset of a collection of random variables is the probability distribution of the variables contained in the subset.

Is the subset corresponding to a marginal distribution could be any non-empty set of the original set?

Assume a n-variables joint distribution, How many marginal distribution could be there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Obviously $2^n$, by this definition.  But 2 of those cases, the empty subset and its complement, might raise eyebrows, so one could say there are $2^n-2$ non-trivial marginal distributions.